# Does deadline_timer::wait yield to other tasks?

Tags: c++, boost, timer, boost-asio

Does calling `deadline_timer::wait` cause other tasks inside an `io_service` to be executed while waiting or does it totally block the io thread if called inside it?

```
io_service service;
io_service::work work(service);
thread thread([&] { service.run() });

service.post([&]
{
   deadline_timer timer(service, posix_time::seconds(100000);
   timer.wait();
});

service.post([&]
{
   std::cout << "HELLO!";
}):

thread.join();
```

Should hello print?

Comment: for clarification, io_service running single threaded?

Comment: @user1810087 correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not, it blocks for that time. [qoute](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/wait/overload2.html):

> This function is used to wait for the timer to expire. This function blocks and does not return until the timer has expired.

See your own [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce84e4d0244ddc08).